# How to replicate CTRL+C in a shell script?

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, copy-paste

I'm running a script that performs a command that lasts too long, so I want to interrupt it. Any help? I've tried to search a lot, and I've been pointed to the kill command. Although, I can't get it to work. By the way, I'm using a Mac OS X. Thanks!

Comment: Be more specific. Are you running the script in the background? Are you waiting for it to complete? What is your script and how are you trying to do...whatever it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Well basically, I am running an asr multicast stream but cannot figure out how to stop it, so I am trying to do this:
asr server --source [source] --config [plist file] --debug | ( sleep 30 && [CTRL+C] )
The problem is that I do not know how to replicate CTRL+C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the process' PID, send it a SIGINT signal:

```
kill -SIGINT PID
```

If you don't have the PID you can try `pkill` or `killall`, but they're somewhat less safe; a PID is the only way to uniquely identify a process. Right after you spawn the other process the PID should be in $!, so you can save it then

```
process-that-takes-a-long-time &
pid=$!
# other stuff
kill -SIGINT $pid
```

Comment: What if I can't find the PID? Is there another way to replicate CTRL+C?

Comment: Be careful with `killall`. On some systems it's similar to `halt`.

Answer (score 0):

[timeout](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/timeout) 10 your_command

Answer (score 0):

To replicate Linux Ctrl+C on a terminal on Mac OS X, use **ctrl+C**!
Its the same keystroke combination
Worked for me (first Steps on Mac)

edit: I didnt read the script is running in background.